# How to view a pivot table with actual column values like access in excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, pivot-table

I've tried searching this but couldn't find an answer because of the wording of the question. If it's been asked before please point me in the right direction.

I have the same exact data in Excel and Access, however, the pivot tables are viewed differently as shown below:

**Excel view and data**
[image: Excel-example]

**Access view, same data**
[image: Access-example]

As you can see the pivot table in access has the actual values (Y, N) whereas in excel it sums up the values. I want excel to display the actual values like Access and not the sum.

I'll be switching over to Office 2013 soon and need to know how to do this in Excel 2013 since pivot tables were removed from Access 2010 in Access 2013.

I have also tried adding data to the columns section but doing so gave a harder to follow and different view as shown below:

[image: Different view]

Comment: Maybe it is just because you are using mock data, but pivot tables are mainly convenient tools for *summarizing* data across dimensions. Your usecase seems to be rather different. If you had a thousand persons you would have a thousand columns with values in just one row, assuming each person went to only one university.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do....

Looks like you will need an extra column in your table showing boolean values for yes/no as 1/0 for both house and car

Then, use those two new columns as your Sum of Values in the pivot table. Right click on the pivot table, go to options, and make sure that you have 'empty cells' set as blank. Then, for each value, you need this custom format
    [>=1]“Yes”;[=0]“No”;
Don't copy and paste it in - it doesn't work (not for me anyway). Type it in manually.

I got the info from here (which probably explains it better) http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/05/07/displaying-text-values-in-pivot-tables-without-vba/

Comment: Nice, before seeing "custom format", I'd have done a formula to the effect. cell=IF(celltoleft="1","Y","N") , then hide celltoleft. Pivot tables might have thwarted that without copy/paste values only and a resize selection too. Custom Formats are a bit quirky on a Mac after you've entered custom format first time, you have to select again from list for it to 'take' initially. But after that it's good to go!